# UnPivot a Pandas Data Set with Merge

Tags: python, pandas

How do I transform this starting data set into a flattened data set with a Python Pandas data frame?

[image: Starting Data]

Like this flattened data:

[image]

I tried to "stack" the data and reset the index, but this produced an undesired result.

```
df = xl.parse("data")
stack = df.stack(-1).reset_index(0)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) (aka "unpivot"):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([["a", "b", 43, 87, 29]], columns=["N", "P", 1, 2, 3])

In [12]: pd.melt(df, id_vars=["N", "P"], value_vars=[1, 2, 3], var_name="Day")
Out[12]:
   N  P Day  value
0  a  b   1     43
1  a  b   2     87
2  a  b   3     29
```

Comment: Hey Andy, just curious why you prefer melt over setting an index and then stacking? Is there a particular advantage? (my datasets almost always have huge, complex `MultiIndex` indexes and columns, so those always feel more intuitive to me.

Comment: @PaulH they do slightly different things. Honestly I rarely use melt, I think it's a bit space-wasteful, I prefer to just leave it as columns. :) That said, I think melt is more efficient than `df.set_index(["N", "P"]).stack()`. For one, melt doesn't drop NaNs... so slightly different

Comment: @AndyHayden the melt function worked when i was importing an Excel file but when I tried the same function with a .csv file, the entire values column is "NaN". Do you know what could have caused that?

Comment: @AMV not sure, it shouldn't matter how it became a DataFrame... would potentially make an interesting new question!